# Pandas to calculate rolling aggregate rate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate a rolling aggregate rate for a time series.

The way to think about the data is that it is the results of a bunch of multigame series against a different teams. We don't know who wins the series until the last game. I'm trying to calculate the win rate as it evolves against each of the opposing teams.

```
series_id     date      opposing_team   won_series
 1          1/1/2000         a            0
 1          1/3/2000         a            0
 1          1/5/2000         a            1
 2          1/4/2000         a            0
 2          1/7/2000         a            0
 2          1/9/2000         a            0
 3          1/6/2000         b            0
```

Becomes:

```
series_id     date      opposing_team   won_series    percent_win_against_team
 1          1/1/2000         a            0                    NA
 1          1/3/2000         a            0                    NA
 1          1/5/2000         a            1                    100
 2          1/4/2000         a            0                    NA
 2          1/7/2000         a            0                    100
 2          1/9/2000         a            0                    50
 3          1/6/2000         b            0                    0
```

Comment: I am confused by the definition of percent_win_against_team. Is it percent of series won? If so, shouldn't it be 0,0,100,100,100,50 or better yet NA,NA, 100, 100, 100, 50?

Comment: Added the NAs; good point. The reason there isn't a third 100 is that it takes place on 1/4/2000, before the first series was won.

Comment: Are series always exactly 3 games? Or are they ended by their last appearance in the data?

Comment: No, they can be any size.

Comment: Then how would one know that a series was over?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't feel like I understand the rule for how you decide when a series is over. Is 3 over? Why is it NA, I would have thought 1/3rd. Still, here is a way to keep track of the number of completed series and (a) win rate.

Define 26472215table.csv:

```
series_id,date,opposing_team,won_series
1,1/1/2000,a,0
1,1/3/2000,a,0
1,1/5/2000,a,1
2,1/4/2000,a,0
2,1/7/2000,a,0
2,1/9/2000,a,0
3,1/6/2000,b,0
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df  = pd.read_csv('26472215table.csv') 
grp2 = df.groupby(['series_id'])
sr = grp2['date'].max()
sr.name = 'LastGame'
df2 = df.join( sr, on=['series_id'], how='left')
df2.sort('date')



df2['series_comp'] = df2['date'] == df2['LastGame']
df2['running_sr_cnt']  = df2.groupby(['opposing_team'])['series_comp'].cumsum()
df2['running_win_cnt'] = df2.groupby(['opposing_team'])['won_series'].cumsum() 

winrate = lambda x: x[1]/ x[0] if (x[0] > 0) else None
df2['winrate'] = df2[['running_sr_cnt','running_win_cnt']].apply(winrate, axis = 1 )
```

Results df2[['date', 'winrate']]:

```
       date  winrate
0  1/1/2000      NaN
1  1/3/2000      NaN
2  1/5/2000      1.0
3  1/4/2000      1.0
4  1/7/2000      1.0
5  1/9/2000      0.5
6  1/6/2000      0.0
```

Comment: Great catch. Three should have been zero. It is against a different team so starts from zero again. So maybe applying this to a groupby would do the trick

Comment: I think it should do what you want now

Comment: Almost, except number 3 needs to be NaN as nothing has been won yet.